# Error upon adding cartridge to OpenShift app

Tags: git, openshift, openshift-cartridge

Am getting the below error upon adding a `cartridge` to my `diy OpenShift application`. The cartridge manifest URL is a raw browsed URL suffixed by `?raw`. Any inputs and / or recommendations would be highly appreciated.

```
Unable to complete the requested operation due to: Unable to load the provided
manifest: (<unknown>): did not find expected <document start> at line 1 column 1
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the repo/manifest file that you are using?  You aren't really providing enough information for anyone to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manifest file you're linking to needs to be in the following format:
http://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#cartridge-metadata

If you're trying to reference a GitHub URL that does not contain a [Source-Url](http://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html#source-url), use the [Cartridge Reflector](https://developers.openshift.com/en/get-involved-extend-openshift.html#the-cartridge-reflector).